# Print from txt file

Tags: python, printing, text-files

I have a group of users. I want to scrape the users from a txt file then write

```
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/user1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
WAIT SECONDS= 27
```

for each one of them until the users have ran out or all the examples have been replaced, How would I do this?

users.txt

```
rrralu
rebeccamacavei
corinnaco_
andrew1996_
thisisme_r
zabiburuziga
be_real_00
officiel_14_leo
thefullersgroup
```

What I have

```
print("\\reading users")
text_file = open("users.txt", "r")
print(text_file.read())
text_file.close()
```

Comment: Please be more clear in your question. In your example, is 'user1' to be replaced with the user name? What do you mean you want to 'write' that: to the console, to a separate file for each user, to one file for all users, or other? What is the format and file name of the file(s)?

Comment: You are correct user1 should be replace with a username and one file for all users. in a txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an instance of the built-in [`string.Template`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings) class. Note the `$user1` I added.

```
from string import Template

template = Template('''\
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/$user1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
WAIT SECONDS= 27''')

with open('users.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(template.substitute({'user1': line.strip()}))
```

**Update**

An even simpler way is to use the `str.format` method common to all strings. The syntax for replacement fields is slightly different (`{user1}` instead of `$user1`), but it has the advantage that you don't have to `import` anything to use it and it plays well with all the other [format string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) options.

```
template = '''\
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/{user1}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
WAIT SECONDS= 27'''

with open('users.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(template.format(user1=line.strip()))
```

Both will product the following output when run with the data in your sample `users.txt` file:

```
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/rrralu
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
WAIT SECONDS= 27
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/rebeccamacavei
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
WAIT SECONDS= 27
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/corinnaco_
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
WAIT SECONDS= 27
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/andrew1996_
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
WAIT SECONDS= 27
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/thisisme_r
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
WAIT SECONDS= 27
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/zabiburuziga
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
WAIT SECONDS= 27
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/be_real_00
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
WAIT SECONDS= 27
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/officiel_14_leo
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
WAIT SECONDS= 27
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/thefullersgroup
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
WAIT SECONDS= 27
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the whole .txt file.

This can be done by opening the file and using the method `readlines()`

Using you code, you have to change this line:

```
print(text_file.read())
```

to

```
print(text_file.readlines())
```

CODE1:

```
print("\\reading users")
with open("users.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

print lines
```

If you want to print only the value from the 7th row... You have to `print lines[6]`

**EDIT:**

After running the Code1, you'll get a list with each name corresponding to an item. Then all you have to do is create your desired link while looping through the list.

```
lines = ['rrralu','rebeccamacavei','corinnaco_','andrew1996_',
         'thisisme_r','zabiburuziga','be_real_00','officiel_14_leo',
         'thefullersgroup']

for line in lines:
    url = 'URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/%s' % (line)
    print url
```

Output:

```
\reading users
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/rrralu
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/rebeccamacavei
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/corinnaco_
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/andrew1996_
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/thisisme_r
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/zabiburuziga
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/be_real_00
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/officiel_14_leo
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/thefullersgroup
```

Comment: Tired it. It just printed out the users. I'm trying to write this line of code for each user  and replace example with a user.

URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/EXAMPLE
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
WAIT SECONDS= 27

Comment: edited my answer. take a look and think how you can improve it to achieve what you want.